# NoAlertPresentException when running scraping using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have the below code to scrape some data using Python Selenium but I keep getting a `NoAlertPresentException` error at various points during the scraping process. The full error is shown below:

```
NoAlertPresentException: no alert open
  (Session info: chrome=109.0.5414.121)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528161 (5b82f2d2aae0ca24b877009200ced9065a772e73),platform=Windows NT 10.0.19045 x86_64)
```

I have tried altering the various `time.sleep` numbers but that still does not seem to stop the error from popping up.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait    
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://mspotrace.org.my/Sccs_list')
time.sleep(20)

# Get list of elements
elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@title='View on Map']")))

# Loop through element popups and pull details of facilities into DF
pos = 0
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['facility_name','other_details','gmaps_url'])
df_out = pd.DataFrame(columns=['facility_name','other_details','gmaps_url'])

for iii in range(1,10): # testing with 10 pages
    for element in elements:
        try: 
            data = []
            element.click()
            time.sleep(10)
            facility_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//h4[@class="modal-title"]').text
            other_details = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="modal-body"]').text
            map_url = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'https://maps.google.com/maps?ll=')]")
            gmaps_url = str(map_url.get_attribute('href'))
            time.sleep(20)
            data.append(facility_name)
            data.append(other_details)
            data.append(gmaps_url)
            df.loc[pos] = data
            WebDriverWait(driver,1).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[aria-label='Close'] > span"))).click() # close popup window
            print("Scraping info for",facility_name,"")
            time.sleep(10)
            pos+=1

        except Exception:
            alert = driver.switch_to.alert
            print("No geo location information")
            alert.accept()
            pass
      
    # click next
    btnNext = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="dTable_next"]/a')
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", btnNext)
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", btnNext)
    time.sleep(5)
    
    # create outputs in df_out
    df_out = df_out.append(df)
    
    # Get list of elements again
    elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@title='View on Map']")))

    # Resetting vars again
    pos = 0
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['facility_name','other_details','gmaps_url'])
```